# Unable to authenticate when using MongoClientSettings

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to connect to a MongoDb database.

- My client: ASP.NET Core 2 with MongoDb.Driver 2.6.1
- My server: MongoDb 3.6.5 Community Edition, stand alone (no replica set), 64-bit on Windows Server 2016.

Authentication by connection string **is** working:

```
public MongoDbContext(AppSettings appSettings)
{
    var connectionString = "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@myDomain.com:27017/myDatabaseName";

    _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    // ...
}
```

Authentication by MongoClientSettings is **NOT** working:

```
public MongoDbContext(AppSettings appSettings)
{
    var credentials = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential(databaseName: "myDatabaseName", username: "myUsername", password: "myPassword");
    var server = new MongoServerAddress(host: "myDomain.com", port: 27017);

    var mongoClientSettings = new MongoClientSettings
    {
        Credential = credentials,
        Server = server,
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Standalone,
        ServerSelectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    };

    _client = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);

   // ...
}
```

> TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 3000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Standalone", Type : "Standalone", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/myDomain.com:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/myDomain.com:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate username 'myUsername' on database 'myDatabaseName'. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command authenticate failed: auth failed.

I have been using the exact same values for both approaches (upper and lower case as well). But only the `MongoClientSetting` approach is throwing an exception. For different reasons though, I would rather use the `MongoClientSetting` approach than the connection string based approach.

Am I missing anything or is this a bug in the MongoDb Driver for C#?

To avoid misunderstandings: In the samples above I exchanged all real values (username, password, etc.) for fake values.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an authentication issue related to the call to `MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential`, which creates the credential using `MONGODB-CR` (challenge-response) authentication mechanism.

Tracked the provided exception down to the [MongoDBCRAuthenticator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/4892dcc5e115a7031d1ba4943cd0ccb55795d2a9/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Authentication/MongoDBCRAuthenticator.cs#L34)

While [deprecated as of MongoDB 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-cr/), the original question indicated using *MongoDb.Driver 2.6.1*

However, the working connection string does not have any `authMechanism` authentication options which would imply that it would use the default authentication mechanism.

Use [`MongoCredential.CreateCredential`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCredential.cs#L162) to create a default credential similar to what worked using the connection string

```
var credentials = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(
    databaseName: "myDatabaseName", 
    username: "myUsername", 
    password: "myPassword"
);
```

Comment: Wow. Good morning Nkosi. Your tipp works. Wonderful. But the fact that my original code is not working is a bug, right? Anyways, thanks so much. My code is much cleaner now.